# Random sequence as input to a linear filter with impulse response

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

I have a random sequence X[n] as the input to a linear filter with impulse response
\begin{equation*}
h[n]=\begin{cases}1/2,\quad&n=0\\
1/2, &n=1\\
0, &else\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
The output random sequence $Y[n]$ is for each outcome $\zeta$
\begin{equation*}
Y[n,\zeta]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{k=+\infty} h[k]X[n-k,\zeta].
\end{equation*}
The mean function of the input $\mu_X[n]$ and the correlation function of the input $R_{XX}[n_1,n_2]$ are given. 
I want to find the the mean function of the output $\mu_X[n]$ and the autocorrelation function of the output $R_{YY}[n_1,n_2]$. Afterwards I want to express the autocovariance function of the output $K_{YY}[n_1, n_2]$ in terms of the two previous functions.

So far my approach for the mean function is: $\mu_Y[n]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{k=+\infty}h[k] \mu_X[k]$

Comment: Where are you stuck ? $\mathbb{E}(\ Y[n+k]\ Y[n]\ )= ?$

Comment: I already don't understand why I should sum from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ when all values are 0 except for $k=0$ and $1$? Why do I want to calculate $E(\dots)$? To calculate $R_{YY}$ my textbook introduces the operator $L_n^*$, with impulse response $h^*[n,k]$, which operates on time index $k$, but treats time index $n$ as a constant. Afterwards, they calculate $R_{XY}[m,n]=L_n^*\{R_{XX}[m,n]\}$ and $R_{YY}[m,n]=L_m\{R_{XY}[m,n]\}=L_m\{L_n^*\{ R_{XX}[m,n] \} \}$ where they result in $R_{YY}[m,n]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} h[m,k]\left( \sum_{l=-\infty}^{\infty} h^*[n,l]R_{XX}[k,l]\right)$.

Comment: You should really try proving those things using what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

$X[n]$ is a sequence of real random variables. First of all we look at the mean $\mu_X[n] = \mathbb{E}(X[n])$, at the variance $R_{XX}[n,0] = \mathbb{E}((X[n]-\mu [n])^2)$ and covariance $R_{XX}[n,k] = \mathbb{E}((X[n]-\mu[n]) (X[n+k]-\mu[n+k]))$.

Then $X[n]$ is said (2nd order) stationary if for all $n$ : $\mu_X[n] = \mu_X[0]=\mu_X$ and $ R_{XX}[n,k] = R_{XX}[0,k]=R_{XX}[k]$.

Now let $x[n]$ be a concrete realization of $X[n]$, ie. a sequence of real numbers.

In that case $$\mu_X = \lim_{N \to \infty}  \frac{1}{2N+1} \sum_{n=-N}^N x[n],\qquad R_{XX}[k] = \lim_{N \to \infty}  \frac{1}{2N+1} \sum_{n=-N}^N x[n]x[n+k]\tag{1}$$
Now this is an exact equality thanks to the $\lim_{N \to \infty}$, but in practice we only have finite signals and we estimate $\mu_X,R_{XX}$ using finite sums $\hat{\mu}_X =\frac{1}{2N+1} \sum_{n=-N}^N x[n], \qquad\hat{R}_{XX}[k]=\frac{1}{2N+1} \sum_{n=-N}^N x[n]x[n+k]\tag{1}$

Finally take some filter $h[n]$ and let $Y[n] = X \ast h[n] = \sum_m h[m] X[n-m]$ another sequence of random variables built from $X[n]$. Let $y[n]$ be a realization of $Y[n]$.

Then $Y[n]$ is again stationary, and $\mu_Y = \mu_X \sum_m h[m],\ \ R_{YY}[k] = \sum_m R_{XX}[k-m] \sum_l h[l] \overline{h[m-l]}$ and the same holds when $R_{XX},R_{YY}$ are computed using $(1)$.